# What do "Tile Groups" do?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, 23.10, window-management, tiling

Ubuntu 23.10 ships with a GNOME Shell extension named Tiling Assistant. It can be installed with this command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-tiling-assistant
```

It adds these settings to the Settings app under "Ubuntu Desktop":

[image: Screenshot of "Ubuntu Desktop" settings]

I'm interested in this section:

> **Tile Groups**
>
> A window is added to a tile group if it doesn't overlap any other windows in the tile group during the moment it was tiled. If a tiled window is raised, the other
> windows of its tile group are raised well

I don't understand the description of this option. What does it do? I'd love it if someone could provide an animated GIF to explain what this option does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have windows A, B and C open. If you tile window A to the left half of the screen, and tile window B to the right half of the screen, they'll be a "tile group".

Now let's say you bring window C to the foreground, and it covers all or part of both A and B. With Tile Groups on, when you bring either A *or* B to the foreground (e.g. by clicking them on the dock, Alt-Tabbing to them), then both A *and* B will be brought to the foreground.

With Tile Groups off, then when you click A again, part of C will still be covering up B.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand it now.